# Specify options for jquery UI Dialog animations?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, effects

I know when you call the dialog you can use

```
.dialog({
  show: 'fade', 
  hide: 'fade'
});
```

But is there any support for options?

e.g.

```
.dialog({
  show: {effect: 'fade', speed: 1000}, 
  hide: {effect: 'fade', speed: 500}
});
```

or even

```
.dialog({
  show: {effect: 'fade', {speed: 1000}}, 
  hide: {effect: 'fade', {speed: 500}}
});
```

I am using `1.8.14`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `duration` instead of `speed`. Like this...

```
.dialog({
  show: {effect: 'fade', duration: 1000}, 
  hide: {effect: 'fade', duration: 500}
});
```

You can also include options like `easing`, `queue`, and even a `complete` callback function. It looks like most of the options accepted by the [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function are accepted in the `show` and `hide` properties.